# spaces need to be edited in the card number textfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am displaying credit card number as 4111 1111 1111 1111 in the text field with numeric keyboard and the spaces are appending programmatically. while editing the text field from left i am not able to edit the space which is in between the card number.

i am appending space in between the card number programmatically. how to remove the space by clicking on backspace in numeric keyboard.

Comment: while editing if the text length is 15 then i am trimming the card number as [textField.text substringToIndex:13]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you have to make your own logic, i am telling the `delegate` method and in this method you have to implement your logic

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //Just implement your logic here
    return YES;
}
```

ufff its too complicated dear , but i solved it , enjoy..

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    static int i =0;
    if (![string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        if (i==4) {
            NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",textField.text];
            textField.text=yourString;
            i=0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    else{
        NSArray *ary = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *str = [ary lastObject];
        if (str.length > 0) {
            i--;
        }
        else{
            i = 4;
        }
        NSLog(@"Rajneesh071");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i knew i have to use this method. Can you tell me the logic